# Why does recursive sequence not work correctly?

Tags: python, recursion, python-2.7

I'm totally new to Python and I'm trying to print the solution for a recursive sequence:

```
#Input sequence variables

a = float(raw_input("type in a = "))
n0 = int(raw_input("type in n_0 = "))
n1 = int(raw_input("type in n_1 = "))
y0 = float(raw_input("type in y_0 = "))


#Define function y_n (forward iteration)

def yn(n):
   if (n==0):
       return y0
   else:
       return (1/n)-a*yn(n-1)

#backward iteration

def yn_back(n):
       return (1/a)*((1/n)-yn(n-1))

if(n1>=n0):
   for i in range(n0,n1+1):   
       print(yn(i))

else:
   for i in range(n0,n1+1):
       print(yn_back(i))
```

But if I run this script with `a=5`, `n0=1`, `n1=30` and `y0=log(5/6)=0.182322` the solutions are very high (from `0.08839` to `3.29e+18`) and the values are negative for even n. The solution is right for `n=1`. For other `n`, the `(1/n)` in the definition of `yn(n)` seems to be ignored.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is probably an integer, so `1/n` is returning `0` for `n` greater than 1:

```
>>> 1/1
1
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
```

To make sure you're using float division, change `1` to `1.0` wherever you calculate `1/n`:

```
(1.0/n)
```

Or convert `n` into a `float`.

Comment: Or even better: `from __future__ import division`

Comment: I have another problem: I want to enter mathematical functions for y0 (e.g. log(6/5)). But it could not get converted to a float, even if I enter "math.log(6/5)". How to manage that?

Comment: I changed "raw_input" to "input" for y0. Now I can type in "math.log(6/5)". How can I just type in "log(6/5)" and it automatically uses "math.log(6/5)"?

Comment: @MarvinKropp: You'll have to add `from math import *` to the top of your script.